# Are there Any Annihilationist schools in Hinduism?

Tags: philosophy, moksha, rebirth, shad-darshana, hell

Among, All the schools of Hinduism, The Madhva school believes in eternal hell for Tamo-yogya Jivas who are beyond saving. There are a few other schools who also believe in the concept of nitya-samsari (i.e infinite transmigration for a certain class of souls which leads them to be permanently denied from moksha). In Similar manner, Are there any schools that adhere to the concept of Annihilationism for the Jivas who are beyond saving?

Comment: No. There aren't. Most of the Abrahamic concepts like - demigods, eternal hell, etc came with Madhva.

Comment: With regard to eternal hell, I'd probably agree, But demigod concept is there earlier to madhva as well as it is believed by ramanujacharya and the alwars. Btw some subschools of Ramanuja and chaitanya vaishnavism subscribe to the concept of infinite transmigration where certain souls while are not sent to eternal hell, but are still permanently denied moksha and remain stuck in samsara

Comment: I'm not sure about Ramanuja's concept, because there is a bit of disparity from what I've read online. Chaitanya Vaishnavism is just another emergent sect out of Madhva, so that's Madhva only (with some tiny modifications).